# Hive : reflect function

Tags: hadoop, reflection, hive, hql

Im trying to use [Reflect](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ReflectUDF) function of Hive which have this signature :

```
reflect(class, method[, arg1[, arg2..]])
```

I want to ckeck if a column `c` with value `hello world !` contains `world`, so I wrote :

```
with a as
(select "hello world !" as c)
select reflect("java.lang.String",c ,"contains", "world") from a
```

But it didnt work because it does not respect the signature, so i tried this

```
with a as
(select "hello world !" as c)
select reflect(reflect("java.lang.Object","toString",c) ,"contains", "world") from a
```

It didnt work also ! I want to know how to apply `reflect` function on a given column ?

Comment: All examples in the Hive manual are for **_static_** methods (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ReflectUDF) and the source code seems to create a new "class" instance by invoking the **constructor-with-no-argument** (http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/1.2.1/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFReflect.java/) so I think you are doomed. Try a custom UDF.

Comment: BTW, I guess your use case involves something more complicated than some simple String primitives (cf. `case when C like '%world%' then True else False end`)

Comment: Thank you  @SamsonScharfrichter, but they said in the doc : `Reflect uses Java reflection to instantiate and call methods of objects; it can also call static functions`. I aim to master the reflect function not the `like` example.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, What about the `isEmpty` method in the Hive manual ? whats the used argument in the example ? how can i apply it for a column ?

Comment: Dunno... have a look at the source code, if you can make sense of it  **:-/**

Answer (score 1):

reflect2 will help.See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20007

```
select reflect2("stackoverflow","length");  
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 13   |
+------+--+
```

but hashCode() won't work.See https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFReflect2.java#L86

```
select reflect2("stackoverflow","hashCode");
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 1:32 Argument type mismatch '"hashCode"': Use hash() UDF instead of this.
```